# Create/Update SQLite database from json file

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite

I'm currently working on an app that maintains a database on device that can be updated via Retrofit at a later date but I'm trying to design a solution that would allow me to cache the current database to put on device when publishing.

Currently this is what happens:

1. Sqlite database is manually created by hand
2. Sqlite database is put into assets folder in app
3. App is run, and database is converted to local database through SQLiteOpenHelper/SQLiteAssetHelper
4. At a later date, the device syncs with the back-end, grabbing a JSON file and manually updating the newly created database.

I'm trying to replace the first step with something more automated.

Is there a way, say I can create a Gradle task that would call my 'sync' code, grab that JSON, and some way to convert it to a Sqlite database to store within the assets folder?

Or perhaps a way to instead use the JSON directly when building the local database in step 3?

I would rather stay away from any other programs just to keep the project simple to use/update.

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to replace first step for testing purposes? I can't undersatand clearly what you want to acheive

Comment: My app has a database that is being updated, and when I publish a new update, I want that database to be as up to date as possible. So I'm grabbing the json and converting it manually before each update, but I'd want a solution that would fetch and save the most up to date version.

Comment: Will your JSON be dynamically defined? Or do you define it once and only its data changes? (adding a field will be rare if any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can go with creating the database directly using a JSON file. You can define a JSON file with multiple nodes each corresponding to a version of your database where every node contains all your DDL commands corresponding to that version of your database.

```
{
  "patches": [
    {
      "version": 1,
      "commands": [
        "CREATE TABLE User ...",
        "CREATE TABLE Login ..."
      ]
    },
    {
      "version": 2,
      "commands": [
        "ALTER TABLE User ...",
        "DROP TABLE Login ..."
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This way you would only need to maintain a single JSON file and update that file for every update you publish for your app. If someone installs your app for the first time then all the DDL commands in your JSON file will be executed, otherwise only those commands will be executed that are corresponding to a higher database version than what is already present in the app before the update.

You would also have to update the `onCreate` and `onUpgrade` methods of your `SQLiteOpenHelper`. `onCreate` method will go through the entire json file and execute all the DDL commands in order(based on version). While `onUpgrade` will only execute the DDL commands under the nodes that have a higher database version.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    List<Patch> patches = parseJson(); // Parse the JSON file and get the patches
    for (Patch patch : patches) {
        int databaseVersion = patch.getVersion();
        if (databaseVersion > oldVersion && databaseVersion <= newVersion) {
            for (String command : patch.getCommands()) {
                database.execSQL(command);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After looking into this solution more, I decided it was the best choice. Not only was I able to implement the `patches` file as described, I was also able to use the same idea for updating the dataset itself. Fetching the json files, converting with GSON, and going through the same logic flow as if I was updating via the network. I did a few optimizations on this idea, by saving the `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE`, the app will only read the JSON file once per update to ensure the dataset is fresh.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont need to cache data page by page( it's mean ur local db save all data from server, and u just need to save current data) just save JSON as String, and on start, parse it again to show offline data, after that, fletch new data if connection is available.

Comment: How would you recommend I change my flow? I currently use SQLiteOpenHelper to create the database, but I would be open to changing to something that can create a database from JSON. I also need some control over how the new database is created, for adding other columns such as "last_viewed" and stuff.

Comment: If you still want save JSON to local db, please use GSON parser, parse JSOn in to your object. After that, match ur object with column for SQLite, and advance column that you want to add such as "last_viewed".

Comment: I'm currently using GSON to parse responses when updating the database later on the network. With your solution, I think I would have to manually add columns after the fact in code. I don't know if that's the best solution, as I'd have to do a lot of checks and could get a bit messy.

Comment: That why i told you just catch as string. If you want save as local db for your specific purpose, noway to make it more simple.

Answer (score 2):

If your JSON tree structure will not change often, you can make a PoJo for it with a tool such as [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). And convert instances using Gson.

You can store this PoJo using Google's new library: [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html).

It can save the PoJo for you (You'll need to annotate it with `@Entity`) in sqlite database, and it can update you on changes in the database.
For more details you can watch the [Google I/O presentations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfHsPGQ6bgE).